# Downloading .j2k or .png files using wget:if else condition

Tags: conditional-statements, wget

I am downloading folder consisting of either j2k or png file using wget. 
Now i want while downloading folder if user is requesting .j2k file and if .j2k file is not existing in that folder then by default download .png file. 
i.e. i want download j2k if present || download .png file.

I have used like this

```
wget -d any.com -i /folder -r -l 1 -nc -A j2k,png
```

-d: download  from this Domain
 -i: download from this foldern
 -r: recursive
 -l 1: follow only 1 link deep
 -nc: no clobber = download only if file doesn't exist
 -A: accept/download only all *.ogg and *.mp3

but using this it is downloading both j2k and png.

Any help will be appreciated.

Referred Links:
[wget if else download condition](https://superuser.com/questions/412114/wget-if-else-download-condition)
[wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You seem to have sort of copy/paste'd your command from the referenced SU question - but with mixed up case, for example `-d` is not the same as `-D`. Also there's a recursive option `-r` in there, which does not make sense in the context of your question.